# How to assign tasks to users with ranking?

Tags: constrained-optimization

I'm trying to write an automatic assignment algorithm for the following problem:

I have $N$ tasks and $M$ users. For each task, I have a ranking for each user for "how related it is to that user". The ranking is a floating-point number in the `[0, 1.0]` range. The sum of all ranks is 1. I need to write an algorithm that will create the overall based assignment for all tasks. It has 2 constraints:

1. Overall best correctness of assignment.
2. Properly balanced - I can't have 1 user assigned 20 tasks while all others are assigned 1-2.

So far, from studying multiple input sets, I found that a task that has a user with a rank over 0.7 should be assigned to that user no matter what, because it's a really strong indicator of a correct assignment. After that, I tried to balance all the remaining tasks.

So, for the input of:

1. `tasks = [t1, t2, t3,... , tn]`
2. `task_user_scores = [[s11, s12,...s1m], [s21, s22, ..., s2m],..., [sm1, sm2, ..., smm]]`
3. `first_iteration_limit = float`, `[0, 1.0]`, I use `0.7`, as I described earlier.
4. `per_user_limit = int`, how many tasks to strive to assign per user.

I do:

Step 1

```
for ti in tasks 
    if some sij > 0.7 
        assign ti to user j
```

Step 2

```
for ti in unassigned tasks 
    compute user deviation(max deviation is abs(n - per_user_limit), udj is abs(assigned_to_j - per_user_limit) from per_user_limit(ud), 
    compute adjusted scores as follows sij * (1 - udj). 
    Select the user from the list using weighted random, if selected user already has more assigned tasks than per_user_limit, select again(the random select happens a finite number of times, I found that 10 is fine). 
    Otherwise, if the user didn't reach per_user_limit assign ti to user j.
```

Step 3

```
for ti in unassigned tasks
    assign ti to the user in the top 5 with the least number of tasks assigned to it.
```

Comment: I tried to format your post to improve the clarity, but the pseudocode is still not very clear. I would recommend that you improve that part even further (so that we don't have very long lines). Anyway, just to clarify, when you say you have a "ranking", you mean that you have a ranking for each user of the tasks that they prefer. So, if task 3 is the more preferred task for user 1, then task 3 will have the highest score for user 1, e.g. 0.9.  If, after task 3, we have task 5, then the score will be like 0.8 for user 1. Right?

Comment: Although you didn't answer to my question above, you may want to look into linear programming, constrained satisfaction problems and constrained optimization.